# Year dynamically into date --- PHP

Tags: php, date, dynamically-generated

Does anyone know how to load current date data dynamically into a date in PHP ?
In example: the year, to automatically update.
I'm trying the following without success.

```
$nowDate = date('d/m/Y');
$cYear = date('Y');             
$dateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/'.$cYear);
$dateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/'.$cYear);

if ($nowDate >= $dateBegin && $nowDate <= $dateEnd)
{
  echo "is between";
} else {
    echo 'OUT!';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** compare `DateTime` objects between each-other:

```php
$dateNow = new DateTime();          
$dateBegin = new DateTime($dateNow->format('Y-01-01 00:00:00'));
$dateEnd = new DateTime($dateNow->format('Y-12-31 23:59:59'));

if ($dateBegin <= $dateNow && $dateNow <= $dateEnd) {
  echo "is between";
} else {
    echo 'OUT!';
}
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/972269)**</kbd>

Comment: I appreciate all of your contribution to solving this problem. Thanks Glavic for your straightforward solution! Lovely. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

watch out data type

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] )
public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

make the same type and compare.

```
$nowDate = date('d/m/Y');
$cYear = date('Y');

$dateBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/'.$cYear);
$dateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/'.$cYear);

// change to DateTime type
$nowDate2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $nowDate) ;
echo $nowDate2->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
echo $dateBegin->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
echo $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d')."\n";

if ($nowDate2 >= $dateBegin && $nowDate2 <= $dateEnd)
{
  echo "is between";
} else {
    echo 'OUT!';
}
```

Comment: Why would we create $nowDate2 from $nowDate? Why not just make $nowDate DateTime object in the first place?